# How to set the scope for defined variables in another file for JSHint in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jshint

How can I set the scope of the defined variables for JSHint to my whole project in WebStorm?

If I have multiple files and imports like `jquery` or `Backbone` I don't need to see the error `JSHint: 'Backbone' is not defined.(W117)`. This is not only form my imported libraries, but also for my own external files.

Some suggestions is that I should disable undefined errors, but this is the functionality that I want to use.

I.E.
In my `main.js` I have this:

```
function Main(){
    // Some epic code
}

Main.prototype.theBestFunctionEver = function(awesome, stuff){
    return awesome + stuff;
}
```

and in `foo.js` I have this:

```
function init(){
    var main = new Main(); // Shows that Main is undefined
    var wrongVar = 6 + unInited // This should always give me an error
    // Rest of init
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSHint works on per-file basis and doesn't 'see' variables defined in other files unless they are added to 'global' list. This can be done by either adding the corresponding comments ('/* global MY_LIB*/ - see http://www.jshint.com/docs/) in code, or by adding variables/functions you'd like to use globally to the 'Predefined' list in Preferences -> Javascript -> Code Quality Tool -> JSHint -> Predefined (,separated).